# Text to Time with Milliseconds

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2016

In column A1 I have 16304238, which represents Hour, Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds, which I want to display in B1 as 4:30:42:380 PM.

I know how to format with hour and minutes, but can't get the seconds and millisecond correct. I tried

```
=TIME(LEFT(E2,2),MID(E2,3,2),RIGHT(E2,2))
```

Which comes out as 16:30:38.000. Also, I'm using

```
[h]:mm:ss.000
```

to format the result. What do I need to use, instead of [h], to get AM/PM instead or military time?

Comment: for AM/PM use `[h]:mm:ssAM/PM`

Comment: Do you have times at 3 AM or 7 AM? How would they display in your original format, is there a leading zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your formula to:

```
=--CONCATENATE(LEFT(E2,2),":",MID(E2,3,2),":",MID(E2,5,2),".",RIGHT(E2,2))
```

[image]

Then format the cell to:

```
h:mm:ss.000 AM/PM
```

[image]

Comment: The formula works great! However, the format is not working, it still displays 16:45:04.60. Steps: Right click > Format > Custom > Type: h:mm:ss.000 AM/PM > Ok

Thanks!

Comment: @Diomedes not sure why it does not work for you, see edit.

Comment: Now I see WHY it doesn't work, but not sure how to fix it. Utilizing the formula, 16304238 becomes 16:30:42.38. If I try to use the format it doesn't work. However, if I add a 0 after the period, making it 16:30:42.038 THEN it displays 4:30:42.038 PM. Obviously, its expecting 3 digits for milliseconds but we are only providing 2. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use the formula as I have it typed with the `--` in the front?

Comment: Yes I did. So I tried copying the column with the formula/results and pasting into a new column, VALUES only. Then set the format nothing. I tried like 20 other similar things with the same results. At then end, I copy the formula column, paste into a txt file, copy from the txt file and pasted into excel. Then set formatting an voila. So for now, giving up on it, since I have the end result. But yes, very weird. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

With `16304238` as a true number in A1,

```
=--TEXT(A1*POWER(10, MIN(0, 6-LEN(A1))), "00\:00\:00.000")
```

This covers 0, 1, 2 or 3 decimal places. The result requires cell formatting as `h:mm:ss.000 AM/PM`.

[image]